# google app (cloud) with php zend framework

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, zend-framework

am just wondering how to upload my php zend framework web application to google cloud ,
i've tried lots of stuff but still no results any help plz ,
its not a big web application but still i have a data base , not a big one , tried downloading the appengine-java-sdk and work around it . but the java sdk wont upload to google ???
i read this article http://www.webdigi.co.uk/blog/2009/run-php-on-the-google-app-engine/
it would make sense if the jdk worked on my windows 7

Comment: What have you actually tried, and what specifically went wrong? "It won't work" is exceptionally unhelpful.

Answer (score 1):

Google App Engine is primarily designed to run Python and Java web applications. It is not intended to be a PHP hosting service, and most PHP applications will not run under GAE without significant modification.

(**NB:** This question was asked before Google's May 2013 introduction of [the PHP runtime for Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/). It *is* possible to run PHP applications on it now, with some limitations; read the linked documentation for details!)

Answer (score 0):

As of November 2013, Google App Engine does in fact have a PHP runtime. I do have a couple of Zend projects running as GAE apps. Setting it up is so easy, too. No need for those lovely .htaccess files. Here's how my app.yaml are configured:

```
application: current-freelance-gig-prj 
version: 1 
runtime: php 
api_version: 1 

handlers: 
- url: /img 
  static_dir: public/img 

- url: /js 
  static_dir: public/js 

- url: /css 
  static_dir: public/css 

- url: /.* 
  script: public/index.php
```

I'm sure there's probably a smarter way to list all those static directories, possibly collapsing them down to a single entry, but still, that is much easier to understand than Apache's rewrite rules.